# Do i have to convert string to double?

Tags: c#

I needed to find the closest number from my variable. For exemple, my variable is fib 1.23 and i needed to find the closest number in order by entry.

Numbers are entering constantly 1.22 , 1.26, 1.33, 1.21 , 1.215, 1.225.

So i needed a code that gives me the closest number from 1.23 which is 1.225 than the closest number from 1.225 which is 1.23 and then the closest number from 1.23...

Someone came up with that code:

```
list.Sort(Comparer<double>.Create((x, y) => Math.Abs(fibo1 - x) < Math.Abs(fibo1-y) ? -1 : Math.Abs(fibo1 - x) > Math.Abs(fibo1 - y) ? 1 : 0));

var output = String.Join(", ", list);
Print(output);
```

The thing is the only way i can use that line is by using String.Join(", ", list);

In a formula:

```
nearclose = ((cma - lowPrice) * list) + lowPrice;
```

The list wont return the closest number in order, i suppose its link to comma, i dont know. Maybe it return a string and need to be convert to double.

Edit:

```
        double pivot = 1.23;

        List<double> numbers = ConstructList();
        numbers.ToConsole<double>("Unsorted");
        numbers.Sort(Comparer<double>.Create((x, y) => Math.Abs(pivot - x) < Math.Abs(pivot-y) ? -1 : Math.Abs(pivot - x) > Math.Abs(pivot - y) ? 1 : 0));
        numbers.ToConsole<double>("Sorted");

        Console.WriteLine("\nDone.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<double> ConstructList()
    {
        List<double> result = new List<double>();
        result.Add(1.22);
        result.Add(1.26);
        result.Add(1.33);
        result.Add(1.21);
        result.Add(1.215);
        result.Add(1.225);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `list[0]` instead of `list`?

Comment: its returning error message: file error code line of code
SampleDisplayBarsAgo.cs Unable to achieve indexing with a 'double' expression CS0021 878 37

Comment: "the closest number from 1.225 which is 1.23"? I don't understand; 1.23 is not in the list. Did you mean 1.22?

Comment: you are right sorry. (1.22)

Comment: "Numbers are entering constantly.." are these string values being entered? string that represent numbers. Or is this a stream of floating point numbers like from a data acquisition system or a sensor?

Comment: Please see [edit] the question and read on how to include a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also `list` is a collection and cannot be used in a numeric formula as such as `nearclose = ((cma - lowPrice) * list) + lowPrice`

Comment: Many formulas return answers 1.23, 1.25, 1.48, 4.25 etc. These are double coming from a merge list. The code is suppose to put order in the list. So i thought that list.Sort would return only one number or at least the closest from the variable fibo1. So i need to extract somehow those numbers from the list in order to be able to input them in the formula. Cause you are right i cannot use them in the formula in their actual form. With var output i can see the numbers but cant use them.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your desired output is.  You talk about putting the list in order, and then you talk about finding the closest number to some (arbitrary?) target.  Are you trying to order the starting list by the _distance from the target_ ?

Comment: You are touching a critical point. I must admit it is difficult to explain correctly.The big list that contains all the result from the formulas returns more than one answer. (1.23, 1.25, 1.48, 4.25 etc.) Get a code to find the closest number from my variable fibo1 = 1.23 is not difficult. The code earlier do the job and tells you the closest number is 1.23. But the list is always updating and returns new numbers (1.25, 1.47, 2.65, 4.58) Once the code have found the closest number of the list it must fund the next closest number from the updated list.

Answer (score 0):

Does that work for you?

```
var result = list.Select(x => new { difference = Math.Abs(x - pivot), value = x }).OrderBy(x => x.difference).First().value;
```

If you need to eliminate the pivot;

```
var result = list.Where(x=> x != pivot).Select(x => new { difference = Math.Abs(x - pivot), value = x }).OrderBy(x => x.difference).First().value;
```

Comment: its returning the right answer no problem with that. But if i input in the formula result: nearclose = ((cma - lowPrice) * result) + lowPrice; its not returning nearclose it returns lowPrice.